# C - Recursion instead of loops

Tags: c, loops, recursion

I made a program that evaluates expressions, for example

```
Enter text: 97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22+73/40+81/15+100
```

output :

```
105.36
```

If any wrong data is given a user gets a response `Incorrect input`

I am wondering if I could replace all my for loops to recursion, but I don't know how could I achieve that. Could anybody help ?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

int my_atoi(const char* tab, int from, int to)
{
    int score = 0;
    int minus = 0;
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
    {
        if (*(tab + i) == 10)
            break;

        if (*(tab + i) == 32)
            break;

        if (*(tab + i) == '-' && from == i)
        {
            minus = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (*(tab + i) == '+' && i == from)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (*(tab + i) > '9' || *(tab + i) < '0')
            break;
        else if (*(tab + i) >= '0' && *(tab + i) <= '9')
        {
            score *= 10;
            score += (*(tab + i) - '0');

        }
    }
    if (minus == 1)
        score *= -1;
    return score;
}
int validate_expression(const char* expr)
{
    if (!expr)return -1;
    int lng = strlen(expr) - 1;
    if (*(expr) > '9' || *(expr) < '0' ||  * (expr + lng) > '9' || *(expr + lng) < '0')return 0;

    int flaga = 0; // flag
    for (int i = 1; i < lng; i++) {
        if (*(expr + i) <= '9' && *(expr + i) >= '0')
        {
            flaga = 0;
        }
        else if (*(expr + i) == '/' || *(expr + i) == '*' || *(expr + i) == '-' || *(expr + i) == '+')
        {
            if (flaga == 1)
                return 0;
            flaga = 1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
int calculate(const char* expr, float* result)
{
    if (!expr || !result || !validate_expression(expr)) return 0;
    if (strpbrk(expr, "i") != NULL) return 0;

    int index = 0;
    float score = 0;
    char sign_memory = 'A';
    int flaga = 0;
    unsigned int i = 1;

    for (; i <= strlen(expr); i++) {
        if (*(expr + i) == '-' || *(expr + i) == '+' || *(expr + i) == '/' || *(expr + i) == '*' || *(expr + i) == '\0') {
            score += (int)my_atoi(expr, index, i - 1);
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (; i <= strlen(expr); i++) {
        if (*(expr + i) == '-' || *(expr + i) == '+' || *(expr + i) == '/' || *(expr + i) == '*' || i == strlen(expr)) {
            flaga = 1;
            if (sign_memory == '+')
                score += (int)my_atoi(expr, index, i - 1);
            else if (sign_memory == '-')
                score -= (int)my_atoi(expr, index, i - 1);
            else if (sign_memory == '/')
            {
                if (my_atoi(expr, index, i - 1) == 0)return 0;
                score /= (int)my_atoi(expr, index, i - 1);
            }
            else if (sign_memory == '*')
                score *= (int)my_atoi(expr, index, i - 1);
            sign_memory = *(expr + i);
        }
        else if (*(expr + i) <= '9' && *(expr + i) >= '0' && flaga == 1) {
            flaga = 0;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    *result = score;
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    char tab[201];
    float result, * pointer = &result;

    printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(tab, sizeof(tab), stdin);

    *(tab + strlen(tab) - 1) = '\0';
    if (!validate_expression(tab))
    {
        printf("Incorrect input");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (calculate(tab, pointer))
            printf("%.2f", *pointer);
        else {
            printf("Incorrect input");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be much clearer to replace `if (*(tab + i) == 10)` with `if (tab[i] == '\n')`.  Using subscripts is sensible; using `*(ptr + idx)` is not; using `'\n'` for newline and `' '` for space is more sensible than using 10 and 32.  Also consider the merits of `<ctype.h>` and `isdigit()`, etc.

Comment: You probably could use recursion; I'm not convinced it would benefit the code.  Do you support parentheses?  Should you?

Comment: I need to use pointers and I need to use recursion now, I've tried implementing it but it's hard for me. Should've known to use it from start..

Comment: `for (; i <= strlen(expr); i++) {` <<- painful

Comment: Pointer notation is going to come down to your instructor's definition of 'using pointers' — using `ptr[idx]` is using a pointer (one of the terms must be a pointer for subscription to be usable), but it uses the pointer more readably than using `*(ptr + idx)`.  As to recursion, you'll need to decide what you are recursing on.  For example, if you support parentheses, you might have code to recurse on an expression when you encounter an open parenthesis (left bracket, aka `(`) and stop recursing when you reach the balanced close parenthesis (aka `)`). And if you encounter another `(`, recurse.

Comment: You can always use "tail recursion" instead of iteration, though it's less efficient in C than in functional languages where it's the expected norm.

Comment: Could you please send me a link or show an example? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would make a function, which does the following:

- Check if there is just one or more operators ("+", "-", "*", "/")
- In case there is only one, perform the calculation.
- In case there are two, perform a tail recursion, as proposed by [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), something like:

```
calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22+73/40+81/15+100")
 = calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22+73/40+81/15") + 100
 = (calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22+73/40+81") / 15) + 100
 = ((calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22+73/40") + 81) / 15) + 100
 = (((calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22+73") / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = ((((calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2-22") + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = (((((calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34-2") - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = ((((((calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68-34") - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = (((((((calculate("97+74/51-98-11+68") - 34) - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = ((((((((calculate("97+74/51-98-11") + 68) - 34) - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = (((((((((calculate("97+74/51-98") - 11) + 68) - 34) - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = ((((((((((calculate("97+74/51") - 98) - 11) + 68) - 34) - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = (((((((((((calculate("97+74") / 51) - 98) - 11) + 68) - 34) - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
 = ((((((((((((97 + 74) / 51) - 98) - 11) + 68) - 34) - 2) - 22) + 73) / 40) + 81) / 15) + 100
```

Comment: What if the expression is unknown?

Comment: @Simonsoft177: what do you mean by an unknown expression?

Comment: U showed me on function calculate("97+......") but what if i got another expression, for example 2+2 or 4/2